# Index optimization for mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a `match-unwind-group-sort` aggregation pipeline in mongo 2.4.4 and I need to speed up the aggregation.

The match operation consists of range queries on 16 fields. I've used the `.explain()` method to optimize range queries *(i.e. create compound indexes)*.  Is there a similar function for optimizing the aggregation?  I'm looking for something like:

```
db.col.aggregate([]).explain()
```

Also, am I right to focus on index optimization?

Comment: There is in the latest unstable: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 but until then no, and no there is no indexes being use past the mathc as such index optimsation is not a good path

Comment: @Sammaye that's wrong, match most certainly does use indexes as does sort.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That's what I just said, I actually said PAST the match, i.e. in the $group

Comment: Index optimization is the only path to better performance.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky not if you have already optimised it as he said in his question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the first question, yes, you can explain aggregates.

```
db.collection.runCommand("aggregate", {pipeline: YOUR_PIPELINE, explain: true})
```

For the second one, the indexes you create to optimize the range queries will also apply to the **$match** stage of the aggregation pipeline, if they occur at the beginning of the pipeline. So you are right to focus on index optimizations.

See [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

**Update 2**

More about **aggregate** and **explain**: on version 2.4 it is unreliable; on 2.6+ it does not provide query execution data. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/2LzAkyaNqe0

**Update 1**

Transcript of an aggregation explain on MongoDB 2.4.5.

```
$ mongo so
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: so
> db.q19329239.runCommand("aggregate", {pipeline: [{$group: {_id: '$user.id', hits: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {hits: {$gt: 10}}}], explain: true})
{
    "serverPipeline" : [
        {
            "query" : {

            },
            "projection" : {
                "user.id" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "cursor" : {
                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 1031,
                "nscannedObjects" : 1031,
                "nscanned" : 1031,
                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1031,
                "nscannedAllPlans" : 1031,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nYields" : 0,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "millis" : 0,
                "indexBounds" : {

                },
                "allPlans" : [
                    {
                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                        "n" : 1031,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 1031,
                        "nscanned" : 1031,
                        "indexBounds" : {

                        }
                    }
                ],
                "server" : "ficrm-rafa.local:27017"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$user.id",
                "hits" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "hits" : {
                    "$gt" : 10
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Server version.

```
$ mongo so
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: so
> db.version()
2.4.5
```

Comment: you can only explain aggregation queries in the unstable as such it should not be consider that you can, you must make the person aware that that this is not production ready and the verison is unstable and likely to change

Comment: Nope, you can explain aggregations in MongoDB 2.4. I do it all the time.

Comment: Really?? Can you prove that? Maybe show the output of an explain?

Comment: Also since an index is only used for $match, $skip $sort and $limit, if they occur before an unwind and a group I am unsure as to your statement that he is right to focus on an index he has already optimised

Comment: Interesting I can get explain too. Hmm I wonder why it is not documented and also why the JIRA states that it shouldn't be there

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I really appreciate the help.  If I hit a wall with index opt, does that leave scaling up with map reduce as the most reasonable alternative?

Comment: Ah I know why, this doesn't work with sharding so the feature was marked as incomplete the whole time, couldn't see that unless you read into related tasks a bit more

Comment: @TomSwifty It probably means you need to look into your workflow, map reduce is a veeeery slow task and is designed for substantial aggregation over time