# running a $sum query on a set that uses a 2GB index causes 20GB of memory usage

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I've got a large-ish set of records (100M) that look like:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "entry_dt" : ISODate("2012-10-19T02:01:35.176Z"),
    "val" : 13.78,
    "order" : {
        "id" : "85PVSQRS4O",
        "orig_dt" : ISODate("2012-10-19T01:25:35.176Z"),
        "discount" : 2.56,
        "year" : 2013,
        "month" : 10,
        "day" : 19,
        "hour" : 25,
        "minute" : 25,
        "dayOfWeek" : 5,
        "week" : 42,
        "quarter" : 3
    }
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e6ed219cea5b5c64c08d8e")
}
```

I'm stress testing the app for max record count per server, memory usage and speed. I pull up the index stats and see that the index on `order.year` is 2400MB. I've got about 40GB of mem on the server. So I run a simple aggregtion:

```
db.data.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match":{"$and":[{"order.year":2013}]}},
        {"$limit": 1000},
        {"$project":{"v":"$v", "year": "$order.year"}},
        {"$group":{"_id":"$year","v":{"$sum":"$v"}}},
        {"$sort":{"_id":1}}
    ]
)
```

(note: this query is being generated from a query object, so might need some tuning)

Comes back in 14ms. So I decide to run it over the whole dataset and WHAM it goes south really fast. If I just let it chunk away it'll take about 10 minutes. What I see is that the memory is going from <1GB to 20GB (which is taking total mem used to 95%).

Db stats:

```
> db.data.stats()
...
{
"indexSizes" : {
...
"order.year_1" : 2516646384,
```

Did I write the query wrong? Why would running a query on an index that is reasonably sized take up so much RAM?

Comment: could you describe what your aggregation query should do?

Comment: @xlembouras get a sum of all transactions in a calendar year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query is a bit weird, could you try running it as

```
db.data.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match":{"order.year":2013}},
        {"$limit": 1000},
        {"$group":{"_id":"$order.year","v":{"$sum":"$val"}}},
        {"$project":{"v":"$v", "year": "$_id"}}
    ]
)
```

I have:

- rewrite the `match` part
- removed the initial `project`
- added project after group
- removed `sort` because you were sorting on a field that you demand to have a certain value

Comment: So far the performance is the same and it's using far more memory than the index size (same as before). Strangely it seems to be ramping up the memory more slowly, so that's helpful. Also your query is returning the year twice.

Comment: @jcollum I would suggest a trick here, try adding a compound index on `{ order.year:1, val:1}` , that way you will not need to seek to the db at all, it will be an index only query, with a slightly augmented index.

Comment: I am looking forward for the results.

Comment: @jcollum within the group phase MongoDB will not use a sum it will load all documents from disk

Comment: @jcollum add _id: 0 to the $project to remove the additional field. As stated the index is only used by the initial match phase. There is a explain option to the runCommand invocation (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591750/2313887)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591750/2313887] that might give you some help. It's not documented for the current stable version but it's there.

Comment: Added the order.year/val index. Even after that, my odd query (it's being generated, so comes out weird sometimes, that code might need optimization) is 20% faster than yours. I think grouping last is the difference.

Comment: @jcollum Probably the big difference in speed is to do with more fields being in your document that the earlier project is doing. Given the bulk size of your data, have you considered processing in batches and appending those results to a collection. When all the batches are complete you could aggregate again on the output collection. Not ideal, considering it goes over the wire, but I'm guessing the result sets are much smaller than the input sets.

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer here was but this is the only answer so it gets the checkmark.