# Increase MongoDB perfomance with sort

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with over 20 million records like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58f8af0f65fc0a38e40a478f"),
  "text" : "Example text",
  "postdate" : NumberLong("1492692751921"),
  "cId" : "58e3cdbe29c8a54394c52c74",
}
```

And an index like this: `{postdate : -1}`

Of course are there more fields, but this are the most important. Now I want to query for it like this:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { 
    "$and" : [ 
      { "postdate" : { "$gt" : 0}} , 
      { "postdate" : { "$lt" : 1497469601983}} , 
      { "cId" : "58e3cdbe29c8a54394c52c74"}
    ]
  }},
  { "$sort" : { "postdate" : -1}},
  { "$limit" : 20}]);
```

But this takes ages. I am wondering if I can increase this performance. I need this query to work faster. What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using aggregate here, is there something else you want to do after this? Put an index on `"postdate"` but also test with a regular query. Also presuming your `"postdate"` field represents milliseconds since epoch, then it's not likely you have values below 0 either, so the lower boundary should be implied. `.find({ "postdate": { "$lt" : 1497469601983 }, "cId" : "58e3cdbe29c8a54394c52c74" }).sort({ "postdate": -1 }).limit(1)`. Most of all, stop using `$and` where you do not need to. All MongoDB query expressions are **already** AND argumemts, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: Hi user6586661; If you have performance problems, then your first step should be to use the [explain functions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to see what query plan the server uses for your query, and how long each query stage takes. That will help you decide where it is running slowly, and inform your choice of possible changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the index:

```
{ "cId" : 1, "postdate" : 1 }
```

This index will index both fields contained in the $match stage while also indexing for the sort results. More information about indexing for sorts can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

You might also want to examine performance by running some explain plans. [The response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591405/index-optimization-for-mongodb-aggregation-framework) contains a guide on how to perform an explain on an aggregation.

Comment: thank you, the index on cId worked. But I've used the index -1 on postdate.