# MongoDB [Index Optimization] perfomance during aggregation stage

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, optimization, mongoose

I have around 50**M** document in my Mongo database called `dma` and I use this aggregation to obtain necessary data `res` and then manipulate with it.

```
async function FormContract(ownerRealm, id) {
    try {
        const res = await collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                date: {$gt:moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days').toDate(), $lt:moment.utc().toDate()},
                id: id, //45 values one by one
                ownerRealm: {$in: ownerRealm} //20 values one-by-one
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$lastModified",
                open_interest: {$sum: "$buyout"},
                min: {$min: "$price"},
                min_size: {$min: {$cond: [{$gte: ["$quantity", 200]}, "$price", "$min:$price"]}},
                avg: {$avg: "$price"},
                max: {$max: "$price"},
                max_size: {$max: {$cond: [{$gte: ["$quantity", 200]}, "$price", "$max:$price"]}},
                stdDevPop: {$stdDevPop: "$price"},
                cp: {$addToSet: "$owner"},
            }
        }]).exec();...
```

Schema of my collection is looks like this:

```
auc: { type: String },
id: { type: Number },
owner: { type: String },
ownerRealm: { type: String }, //20 unique values
bid: { type: Number },
buyout: { type: Number },
price: { type: Number },
quantity: { type: Number},
timeLeft: { type: String },
lastModified: { type: Number }, 
date: { type: Date, required: true }
```

As for now, there are couple of words about my problem. 
I have ~15**M** documents covered with that `$match` query `date: {$gt:moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days').toDate(), $lt:moment.utc().toDate()},`

Just to be sure, I needed only new docs for the latest day, so obviously they will be inserted in the end of collection

And then I need to make 20 (realms) x 45 (ids) `aggregation` queries after it. My function works fine, but it's execution ultimately.. ehm long.

Remember, I am not saying that it's slow!

Use case:

- If I use `for (ownerRealms.length)` inside `for(id.length)`

  ```
  for (let i = 0; i < ownerRealms.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
          FormContract(ownerRealm, id)
  ```

  that `20 servers x 45 id = 900` queries would form necessary data one
  by one without highload on CPU and RAM in about ~20 mins for each
  server, or `20 mins x 20 servers = 400 mins` *or ~6 HOURS!*
- Or if I use `for(id.length)` and `map(servers)`

  ```
  for (let j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
      const data = await Promise.all(ownerRealms.map(async ({ ... }) => {
           FormContract(ownerRealm, id)
  ```

  that would be async
  20 `$aggregation` queries one-by-one 45 times. Or 1 hour per 10 ids
  or ~4.5 Hr (*much better right?*) But it generates a-lot-of load on
  CPU (almost all cores at @90% utilization, sick)

I operate machine with 7 cores, 7Gb RAM and 80'000+ IOPS SSD so I guess I'm doing something wrong if I accept 90% CPU load for 4.5 Hrs

So is there any idea what will be better for optimization? First-of-all I create index in this collection and it looks like this:

```
lastModified:-1
ownerRealm:1
date:-1
id:-1
```

But according to Mongo Compass it has 0 usage, and stores in separate collection of DB called `undefinded`. Pic here:

[image]

So what's the problem? Am I going it wrong? Should I create a better index. Or there is another way that I'm missing out, like storing data during `$match` stage somewhere else? Or use `$sort` stage? I have read that `$match` query should be first, because it calls all the collection.

I have already checked this **StOv** questions: [Index optimization for mongodb aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591405/index-optimization-for-mongodb-aggregation-framework?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Increase MongoDB performance with sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553811/increase-mongodb-perfomance-with-sort?noredirect=1&lq=1) and already checking `dba.stackexchange` for something useful.

Comment: My index have 0 usage probably, because `mongoose` don't support `.explain()` from the box

Comment: Your index has zero usage because the "prefixed field" is not `date`, and that's the only field which can be used in an index for an aggregation pipeline since it's the only field referenced in the `$match` as the **very first** pipeline stage, which is the prime condition for any index to be used.

Comment: Thus the only index which can improve this would be `date: 1, id: 1, owner_realm: 1`. Read [Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) under Compound Indexes in the core documentation.

Comment: But why `date: 1...` instead of `date: -1`?  According to docs it's about `sort` order, but I need newest docs, not oldest

Comment: Actually if you "according to the documentation" actually read it, then B-tree indexes ( which they are ) really don't care which direction. All it really does is as noted a "default sort order" of returned results. So it's not like it makes a difference finding "newer" faster or anything. And if you were paying attention `aggregate()` cannot use an index for sorting in any other stage then the **first stage**.

Comment: Excuse me, @NeilLunn one more question about indexes, as for now I'm reading `Index Intersection` part. For example I have a script  in another `.js` with `$match: {ownerRealm:ownerRealm , lastModified:lastModified}. And I want create an index for it, so should I create a separate index and point it it? (and for every `$match` query, that I want it to) or I can create one meta-index with `date: 1, id: 1, owner_realm: 1, lastModified: 1` and it will cover both `$match` (script from this question and script from another file)

Comment: Without wandering "off-topic" for the question here, the `ownerRealm` ( or `owner_realm` or whatever ) field would not be a **prefix** so it's not being selected. I pointed you at documentation for the reason you should probably take some more time to digest how indexing and selection actually works.

Comment: No need to worry about `offtopic` I just re-name it, actual question was about optimization and your comment about "correct" indexing helped me very much (I receive data in couple of mins) So, I'll be pleased if you add/re-write your comment as an answer, and I'll mark my question solved