# MongoDB aggregate query performance improvement

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, aggregation-framework

I recently started shifting data from Microsoft SQL Server to MongoDB to obtain scalability. All good in term of migration.

The document has 2 important fields: customer, timestamphash (year month day).

We imported only 75 Million data in Azure Linux where we install MongoDB.
After adding compound index on both fields, we are having the following problem:

On 3 Milion data (after filterin) it takes 24 seconds to finish an aggregate group by count by customerId. The SQL Server gives the result in less then 1 second on the same data.

Do you think Casandra will be a better solution? We need query performance on big number of data.

I tried disk write, giving the VM more RAM. Nothing works.

Query:

```
aaggregate([
{ "$match" : { "Customer" : 2 } }, 
{ "$match" : { "TimestampHash" : { "$gte" : 20160710 } } }, 
{ "$match" : { "TimestampHash" : { "$lte" : 20190909 } } }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "Device" : "$Device" }, "__agg0" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }, 
{ "$project" : { "Device" : "$_id.Device", "Count" : "$__agg0", "_id" : 0 } }, 
{ "$skip" : 0 }, 
{ "$limit" : 10 }])
```

**Update:**
I used 'allowDiskUse: true' and the problem was solved. Reduced to 4 seconds for 3M data filtered.

Comment: "After adding an index on both fields" -- did you create a compound index on both fields or two separate indexes? Could you share the exact indexes you created & the query patterns you're trying to support?

Comment: I created a compound index on both fields, tested with explain that the index is used.

Comment: Thanks! What order is the compound index in? Customer first, right? Is that aggregation the main query you're running? You could consider adding Device to make it a covered query

Comment: On mongo documentation, the group by statement does not use index. I solved the problem with {allowDiskUse:true}.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter a [similar problem before, during this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169048/mongodb-index-optimization-perfomance-during-aggregation-stage), and to be honest, I guess Cassandra is better in your certain case, but the question was about Mongo aggregation query optimization, right?

As for now, one of my collections have more then 3M+ docs, and shouldn't take 24s for aggregation queries if you build indexes correctly.

1. First of all, check out the index usage via Mongo Compass. Does Mongo actually using it? If your app `spam` queries to DB and your `index` have 0 usage (as in example below) than, as you already guessed it, something wrong with your index.
   [image]
2. The Second thing is, using `explain` method ([this doc will help you out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/)), to check out more info about your `query`.
3. And for the third: index field sorting matters. For example if you have `$match` stage with 3 fields and you request docs by fields:

```
{ $match: {a_field:a, b_field:b, c_field:c} }
```

then you should build `compound` index on a,b,c fields in the exact same order.

There is always some kind of DB architecture problem. I highly recommend you not to `stockpile` all data inside one collection. Using `{timestamps:true}` on insertion (it created two fields, like `createdAt:` and `updatedAt:`

```
        {
            timestamps: true
        }
```

in your schema, store old-time/outdated data in different collection and use `$lookup` [aggregation method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for them, when you really needs to operate with them them.

Hope you'll find something useful in my answer.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your time. I`ve tested with explain, the index is used, the problem is with the big data. On a 70M+ documents, i filter them to 3M+ documents and apply a group by on a field and in the projection phase I do a count based on that filed.

Comment: I found a solution for time events where you save in one document all the data from 1 month but the migration will be too hard. Just trying to finding better solution.